# Adding foreign keys to an already existing database

Tags: sql, database, mapping, foreign-keys, spreadsheet

I'm trying to export data from an Excel spreadsheet into a fairly complex relational database.  The spreadsheet indicates "foreign keys" by stating the names of other objects.  (Luckily, I have some control over the spreadsheet, so I can guarantee these names are unique AND that the objects they reference actually exist).

I have a program that can recreate these tables in a MSSql database, but it can't automatically link them to each other.  Besides, I don't want to use the actual names of the objects as the primary key since eventually the database will be large.

So, if I have many existing but unconnected tables which refer to each other by their "name" fields, how can I add a foreign key that links them by their IDs?

A simplified version of what I have:

```
Parent
ID: 1 (PK)
Name: Mary

Child
ID: 2 (PK)
Name: Jane
ParentName: Mary
```

And what I want to achieve:

```
Child
ID: 2 (PK)
Name: Jane
ParentID: 1 (FK)
```

Thanks for any help!  I wasn't able to find an example of how to add a foreign key mapping after the fact, or on a different field.

Comment: Is this a one-time thing, or are you going to have to import data from this spreadsheet regularly?

Comment: @Catcall: I have to do it regularly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [`ALTER TABLE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx) syntax for MSSQL. You can come up with something like this to add the constraint to the table:

```
ALTER Child
ADD CONSTRAINT Child_Parent_FK FOREIGN KEY (ParentID) REFERENCES Parent(ID)
```

Then once the constraint is in, try something like:

```
UPDATE Child 
SET ParentID = (SELECT ID FROM Parent WHERE Name = ParentName)
```

That should work if you can guarantee the `Name` of the Parent is unique. Otherwise you can add `LIMIT 1` to the end of the query. But if there are multiple Parents with the same `Name`, you're going to need to add extra logic (which isn't specified in your original post).

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: Oh, yes. I suppose it is missing a bit. Let me add some more.

Comment: I believe the issue that OP is facing is that Excel spreadsheet contains name of the parent, but the database table should contain the ID of the parent.

Comment: @Olaf, did you read the updated answer? I think it satisfies the OP's question.

Comment: I guess I was reading your answer right before you updated it :-) +1 from me.

Comment: And I recommend dropping the `ParentName` column from `Child` after you're done, to avoid an un-normalized database.

Comment: @X-Zero: care to explain why you think the `ParentName` column violates first normal form? Hints [here](http://www.dbdebunk.com/page/page/622341.htm): "From the context, by normalized here the writer presumably means 3NF.  This usage is common but sloppy; strictly speaking, normalized just means first normal form (1NF)... Strictly speaking, we can't say a given database is or is not in 3NF--3NF is something that is or is not satisfied by a given table."

Comment: @onedaywhen - Sorry, you're right, I'm thinking of 3NF, not 1NF.  And the point about me saying the *database* is 'unnormalized' is also good.  I tend to be at least decent at conceptual designs, but am terrible at the term definitions (no actual classes for SQL, except some performance stuff - all self-taught).

Comment: Thank you!!  Yes, I can guarantee the Name is unique.  One last question re: @X-Zero's suggestion: I will have to perform this operation many times, how can I drop ParentName when I'll have to add new items with that column?

Comment: You drop `ParentName` once you're done with the initial upload to the revised database (and not before).  Afterwards, you do `INSERT` statements that `JOIN` to the `Parent` table, and get the parents' ids that way.

Comment: @X-Zero: I'd be surprised if the OP can count on that kind of join working in the general case. I'd expect new parents to show up from time to time in his Excel spreadsheet--they won't exist in the parent table.

Comment: Hmm, true.  Although given some of the way his question is worded, it sounds like he only has `ParentName` in this particular worksheet (and the actual parents are in another sheet).  Actually, this sounds like the perfect candidate for an updateable view/trigger setup, if this is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're going to be doing this regularly, I think you should import into a staging table. I like to isolate staging tables in their own schema.

Use the staging table to retrieve or generate the keys you need, then insert/update your OLTP tables based on the data in the staging table. Finally, truncate the staging table.

Comment: Thank you!  This is not a direct answer to my original question, but it's what I ended up doing. :)

Comment: This isn't my first rodeo. I know the difference between answering a question and solving a problem. (See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/161666 ) I'm not asking for points, but you can upvote any answer you like, and you can change your accepted answer at any time.

Comment: I will definitely upvote this suggestion as soon as I get enough "reputation"! :)